# jdbc batch insert and query vs single inserts with gernerated key

Tags: select, jdbc, insert, prepared-statement, batch-updates

I want to insert alot of rows into a table that generates the keys automatically. JDBC doesn't guarantee that getting the generated keys will work on a batch update.

`It is implementation-defined as to whether getGeneratedKeys will return
generated values after invoking the executeBatch method.` (JDBC 4.0 Specification 2006, p. 135).

I have got two choices. Insert every row separately and get the key.Or do a batch insert and then query for the keys.

To avoid round-tripping for querying multiple keys I could use this approach [here](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2). Having e.g. 5 prepared statements with different sizes. And then breaking my "batch query" into the smallest possible statement.

What is the faster method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

I have no numbers whether `executeBatch()` is actually faster than using a `PreparedStatement` repeatedly, so my suggestion is this:

1. Try whether `getGeneratedKeys()` works for your JDBC driver. If it doesn't work, batched inserts won't work for you anyway.
2. Write a test case for both and measure the performance. That gives you real data to base your decision on. Everything else is just guesswork (and wrong 90% of the time).

**[EDIT]** If you want to keep your app db agnostic, add the test to your app and run it on a temp/test table. If the test succeeds, chose an implementation that uses batched updates, otherwise fall back to brute force.

Comment: Oh, I though `getGeneratedKeys()` is a must for the driver, but it isn't. I want to keep the application database independant, if possible.